# No sound on Raspbian when using root

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm having a really weird issue on my Raspberry. I need to play sounds with it and I need to do it inside a script which requires sudo to work. However, for some reason, when I try to play sounds with sudo, it doesn't work.
No errors, it just doesn't make any sound (I tried with several libraries, none worked). It does work if I'm using omxplayer.
If I don't use sudo, everything works fine.
Anybody had a similar issue?

Edit: I added one of the code I used (this works just fine on another Raspberry)

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

print("Going forward")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: maybe login as root and after than run code without `sudo` - and see if it gives some error message. `root` may have different privilages or different modules (if you install modules with --user or in `virtualenv`). OR maybe you should change some privilages in your user to have access without `sudo`.

Comment: Typically the user running the process needs to be in the audio-output group.  I can't imagine why this wouldn't work for root though.  It's not an audio-volume thing right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 3.5mm jack or HDMI?
One thing I have noticed in the past is that if I run `alsamixer` as `user=pi` the default device is the 3.5mm aux jack. However if I run `sudo alsamixer` the default device is now HDMI. Never looked in to why, just know that's a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Spent nearly a day trying to enable the analog out when using the root user.

First make sure the default user (pi) has audio:

```
aplay sound.wav
```

If that works then copy the audio configuration to the root user home, try this:

```
sudo su
cd
cp /home/pi/.asoundrc .asoundrc
reboot
```